# How do I use isServerSideGroupOpenByDefault in older version of ag grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

In my project I am using older version of the ag-Grid and isServerSideGroupOpenByDefault was released in v25.3.0. Is there any way I can use isServerSideGroupOpenByDefault in older version or is there any alternative for isServerSideGroupOpenByDefault.

Note: Upgrading version is not an option.